# Discord.py permissions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot for a community server, and I am struggling to get a purge command to only activate when called by users with the "admin" role. The "role check" section of the command does not work. I have tried workarounds such as enforcing that the command is only callable within an #admin-commands channel, where the channel is specified within the command, however that wouldn't work. Also, the role that I am trying to make able to use this command doesn't have the "administrator" permission. I have already searched the API documentation and couldn't find anything relevant. I am trying to avoid using the commands extension as I don't have any experience using it, but if anyone has any tips that can be helpful, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `command however the "role check" section of the command doesn't work` why not fix this issue first before introducing more issues to your problem

Comment: The commands extension has [`has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role), you could look at [the implementation of that](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/671a19a24a620396d403b3c3cb3af2ad5bb13876/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1364)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a cog with `(self,ctx,amount:int)`

You can use:

Make sure to enable developer mode and right click and click Copy ID on the admin channel.

```
if ctx.message.channel.id != (CHANNELID):
    return await ctx.send("Wrong channel.")
```

This would help it being in the correct channel, I will find a way for a role only way of doing the deletion.